# Correct dependencies do not trigger rebuild

Tags: scons

*Premise:* at our company, we are using python 2.7 with SCons 2.3.

The stucture of our [project](https://github.com/imuzzolini-vigrade/scons_question_001) is as follows:

```
.
├── 3rd_party
│   └── ccur
│       ├── SimWB-2020.1
│       │   └── include
│       │       └── simwbversion.h
│       ├── SimWB-2022.1
│       │   └── include
│       │       └── simwbversion.h
│       └── SimWB-any
│           └── include
│               └── simwbversion.h
├── SConstruct
├── src
    ├── SConscript
    └── main.cpp
```

We have the following `SConstruct`:

```
Decider("MD5-timestamp")

opts = Variables(None, ARGUMENTS)
opts.Add(
    EnumVariable(
        "simwb_version",
        "current simwb version",
        "any",
        ["any", "2020.1","2022.1"],
    )
)

env = Environment(options=opts)
env.Tool("gcc")

SConsignFile("out/signatures")

SConscript(
    "src/SConscript",
    variant_dir="out",
    duplicate=False,
    exports=["env"],
)
```

...and the following `src/SConscript`:

```
Import("env")

lenv = env.Clone()
lenv.AppendUnique(CPPPATH=["#3rd_party/ccur/SimWB-$simwb_version/include"])
lenv.StaticObject(lenv.Glob('main.cpp'))
```

The file `main.cpp` is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "simwbversion.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("SIMWB RPMVERSION is %s\n", RPMVERSION);
    return 0;
}
```

By using the argument `simwb_version`, we can choose which include directory will be passed to the compiler when compiling `main.cpp`.

Now, if I invoke `scons --tree=prune simwb_version=any out/main.o`, the target gets built as expected and the dependencies of `main.cpp` are as follows:

```
+-out/main.o
  +-src/main.cpp
  +-/usr/local/bin/g++
  +-3rd_party/ccur/SimWB-any/include/simwbversion.h
```

If I then try to build it with option `simwb_version=2022.1` the target should be rebuilt since the included `simwbversion.h` is different. However, that does not happen even if the dependencies are computed correctly:

```
+-out/main.o
  +-src/main.cpp
  +-/usr/local/bin/g++
  +-3rd_party/ccur/SimWB-2022.1/include/simwbversion.h
```

It is highly likely that the problem is due to SCons `2.3`; we tried to build with SCons `4.3.0` and everything works as expected. Unfortunately, we will be stuck with SCons `2.3` for at least the rest of this year.

**Question:** Could you please give some hints about some patch that we could apply to SCons 2.3?

Comment: Maybe someone smarter than me will be able to draw some conclusions from how little information you've gave as but if I were you, I would try really hard to create a small example that illustrates the problem or I would prepare to not get an answer. The usual approach is to make a copy of the program and gradually remove all the code that doesn't cause the error. This should result in a short code snippet which either makes the problem obvious or if not, it can be posted to SO.

Comment: Possibly some digging with the `--tree` option, or the separate `sconsign` utility, might reveal more information about what SCons thinks the node tree looks like, and the `--debug=prepare` option is supposed to show you whether various targets are being considered for rebuilding.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I will rewrite the question in a better way!

Comment: Why are you stuck on SCons 2.3?  There is the scons-local package you could use as well..

Comment: Can you experiment with SCons 3?  3.1.2 was the last release supporting Python 2.7, and if it works, there's a narrower window to zoom in on where a fix might have been made that would affect you.

Comment: @bdbaddog we are still using python 2.7 with scons 2.3 because the set of scons tools developed in 15 years are difficult to be ported quickly and safely... however we definitely plan to migrate to python3 and latest scons

Comment: @MatsWichmann I tried with python2 and scons 3.1.2 and it works as expected

Comment: Yes. (at least) 2.3. < SCons < 4.0.0 will work with Python 2.7

Comment: Well, it should in theory be possible to git bisect the changes in SCons/Node between 2.3 and 3.1 to try to spot where the behavior changed.  Unfortunately, this is kind of awkward, there seems to be a lot of refactoring that happened in that area, and since then the SCons tree got rearranged. If you feel motivated to try you could attempt other SCons versions and see if it can be narrowed down that way.

Comment: I reproduced the problem with versions 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 3.0.0 and 3.0.1.
I tried also 3.0.2 but cannot install it (`pip install scons==3.0.2` failed).
Then I installed 3.0.3 and the issue disappeared.

Something was committed between 3.0.1 and 3.0.3 that fixed the issue.

I did a `git diff 3.0.1 3.0.3 --stat` to understand what changed. I suppose that is something under `src/engine/SCons` but... any idea about where I should search?